# Making my javaScript popup to appear once

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I am creating a JavaScript popup. The code is as below.

The Issue:

The script below works fine, but I need to make the popUp to appear only once on my page. i.e, when the user closes the popup, it should not appear until the user restarts the browser or clears his cache/cookie.

I know there are similar questions but I couldn't find an answer that was using the same script I'm using so I apologize in advance. Please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000);
  $("#close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px #000;
}
body {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/kO2Ffje.png?1') center top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="popup panel panel-primary">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cVJrCHU.jpg" alt="popup">
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button id="close" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Close button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use a cookie - What scripts did you find and reject? The duplicate I found is using something almost identical to what you use

Comment: Here's the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/rxLdsv32/1/

Comment: @mplungjan here is the script I found and couldn't use -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131542/how-do-i-make-an-image-automatically-popup-on-my-main-page-when-someone-goes-to. Can you share the one you've found?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gpkv6uu6/ `if ($.cookie("seen") != "yes") {
    $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    $.cookie("seen","yes");
  }` - please note the external cookie script

Comment: "Didn't work" ? did you include the [cookie script](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: @mplungjan I included the cookie script and the popup is no longer showing up. It's also not showing here -- jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gpkv6uu6. I'm I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It was JSFiddle that did not want to include the raw github. I [changed the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gpkv6uu6/) to use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js and to include a seen=no button

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I'm not sure if the script is causing this but the pop up is now randomly appearing on other pages even though I only want it to show on the home page once in a single session. Is there a way to modify the code to do that?

Comment: Add `,{ path: '/' }` after "yes"

Comment: Great! I was able to figure it out. I appreciate your time @mplungjan